# Junos not automatically advertising an address configured on loopback interface to OSPF

Tags: ospf, juniper-junos

According to [JNCIP study guide(page 156)](http://hydra.ck.polsl.pl/%7Ehelot/ipad/JNCIP/Ch3_from_JNCIP_studyguide.pdf) from 2003, the Junos should advertise a prefix on `lo0.0` interface to OSPF if the RID is not manually configured:

> JUNOS software automatically advertises a stub route to the interface from which the RID
> is obtained; therefore it is not actually necessary to explicitly configure lo0 as an OSPF interface
> to meet the lo0 connectivity requirements of this configuration example.

Has this behavior changed in the newer Junos releases? For example, with such configuration the `10.0.0.3` address configured on `lo0.0` interface is not advertised to OSPF:

```
root@r3> show configuration routing-options

root@r3> show configuration protocols ospf
area 0.0.0.0 {
    interface ge-0/0/0.0;
    interface ge-0/0/1.0;
}

root@r3> show interfaces lo0.0 terse
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
lo0.0                   up    up   inet     10.0.3.3            --> 0/0

root@r3>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this changed back in Junos 8.5.  You must now explicitly configure lo0.0 (ideally as a passive interface) to advertise the network.